Impact of ONTR on repo
How would one estimate the impact of a change in the yield of the on-the-run (OTR) bonds on the repo rate?
One approach I considered is using PCA. I would run PCA on the OTR yield curve (including the 2-, 3-, 5-, 7-, 10-, 20-, and 30-year OTR points) along with the overnight SOFR rate. By doing this, I could decompose, for example, a 1 basis point move in the 30-year point as a combination of PC1, PC2, and PC3. This would allow me to quantify how much SOFR is affected by a move in the 30-year point. Then, assuming the repo rate is a constant spread over SOFR, I could estimate how much the repo rate is affected by changes in the OTR yield curve.
Does this method seem sound, or are there any other robust approaches I should consider?
Ultimately, the OTR curve is essentially a SOFR curve since all cash flows are discounted using SOFR. When attempting to derive the discount curve from the OTR points, I effectively input an overspecified curve due to the inclusion of all the OTR points (because of the coupon cash flows), resulting in a discount curve that is the SOFR discount curve. Therefore, including the overnight SOFR rate initially seems accurate to me, though I may be overlooking something. Perhaps it would be better to first derive the discount curve from the OTR points, then add the overnight SOFR rate, and perform PCA on this adjusted curve.

The SOFR rate is essentially dependent upon the central bank rate, set by the FED's committee. It is not dependent upon 30y treasury rates. I would suggest you are looking for something that will not help you. If there is any causation I would suggest it is rates of OTR bonds that depend on the repo rate.

trying to understand the question as attack68 said. This is the target fed funds (FF) rate https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DFEDTARU - https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DFEDTARL . this is the effective rate https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/EFFR , this is SOFR https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SOFR - are you trying to explain those SOFR movements that are not explained by FF? If we look, for example, at the period 2023-08-01 to 2024-08-01 : no FF movement, but SOFR moved 5.30-5.40, is that what you're trying to explain?

@Attack68 Yes I see. Since it's the repo rate that impact the OTR yields can't I just say the OTR yield is correlated to the repo rate and hence modify the repo rate using simple correlation? Since it's the repo rate that impacts the yield of the OTR, if I shock the OTR it should change the repo even if it's not the OTR that causes the repo rate to change, it is just to have a "consistent" curve

@DimitriVulis Thanks for your answer. I am just trying to get the new repo rate of bonds after I shock the yield curve. If I shock my curve the repo rate of my bonds can't stay intact since it's the repo rate that impacts the yield curve. The repo rate of a bond is a spread over SOFR so I was just thinking about assuming a constant spread and trying to understand how the OTR yield curve is linked to SOFR. If I move my yield curve => SOFR should move, but how?

The number of ice cream sales are correlated with (and caused by) the weather. You are trying to predict the weather by building a PCA of ice cream sales and then shocking ice cream sales to infer the weather. Simply put, I would never do this. I would derive a better means of predicting the weather.
